# Add the Outlook signature to a mailto link

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hyperlink, email-signature, mailto

I'm using a program that utilizes raw markdown, so I'm beholden to those rules.

I'm trying create a `mailto` link that I can give my employees that will prepopulate all appropriate fields, including the body. I'd like their signatures to appear in the email, but using a standard `mailto:person@company.com?subject=Hello&body=Hi%20there` eliminates their signatures.

Is there a way that I can create a `mailto` link that will add whatever default signature they have set? This is complicated by the fact that everyone in the company has differently-named signatures, but I'm assuming there has to be a way to add whatever default signature is set in Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, I'm afraid that we could not make it automatically add default Outlook signatures when already added message body content. Outlook might consider signatures as part of message body, so when you set message body with your template, it will no longer add the default Outlook signature. Similar thread: [mailto link doesn't add Outlook signature in letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020703/mailto-link-doesnt-add-outlook-signature-in-letter).